# Vertical/horizontal centered/middle scaling image with fixed top and bottom text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple webpage using bootstrap that has some text fixed centered at the top and some more centered text fixed to the bottom of the page.

In the middle of the page I need an centrally horizontal and vertically placed image that scales depending on resolution/device.

The page needs to be full height of the viewport.

I have tried using the following code but it doesnt work properly and is a miss and there must be a simpler way of doing it?

The logo image is 450px x 480px

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>


        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .holder {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        .fill {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .col-md-12 {
            position: relative; 
            min-height:100vh!important;
        }

        .toptext{
            background-color:#ffffff!important;
            z-index:99999!important;
        }

        .bottomtext {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff !important;
            z-index: 99999 !important;
        }

        .middleimage > img {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            z-index:1!important;
            max-height:350px!important;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width: 767px) {
            h3 {
                font-size: 16px !important;
            }
            .bottomtext{
                bottom:80px!important;
            }
            html,body {
                overflow: hidden!important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:567px) and (max-width: 767px) {

            .bottomtext {
                bottom: 80px !important;
            }

            html, body {
                overflow:visible !important;
            }

            .middleimage>img{
                max-height:100px!important;
            }

        }

        @media screen and (min-width:760px)  {

            .bottomtext {
                bottom: 0 !important;
            }

            html, body {
                overflow: visible !important;
            }

            .middleimage > img {
                max-height: 480px !important;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container fill">
        <div class="holder">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                    <div class="toptext text-center">
                        <h3>Top of page info</h3>
                        <hr>
                    </div>

                    <div class="middleimage">
                        <img src="/holdingfiles/mylogo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive " />
                    </div>

                    <div class="bottomtext">
                        <hr>
                        Bottom of page / footer info
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so basically you want it to cover the entire page vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Are you wanting the image to max out at 450x480?  And are you wanting it to scale smoothly or jump to different sizes as it does now?  Your header and footer are scaling it seems, so what do you mean by taking up the height of the viewport?

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback.  What I need is yes, the image should max out at 450x480.  My code is not entirely correct which I why I asked for help.  I don't think the top and bottom text should be scaling, it just needs to sit the centered at the top and bottom respectivley, with the image scaling accordingly in-between the two.  This is so that it looks ok on desktop, mobile, tablet etc.  I tho;ugh about maybe using a background-div in-between the top and bottom text but wasnt sure how to do that or to make it scale, plus it having to be full screen height complicates things for me.

Comment: My way is probably far too complicated perhaps?

Comment: i think background div might be easier, let me see what i can do

Comment: Forget about an img tag, use a background image and `background-size: contain`.

Answer (score 0):

Carl,

Since you are using bootstrap, go with 'img-responsive' class on div/img and it should scale nicely.

EDITED:  you can use it as background image for your div:  check out the following link which should give you what you want

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I have tried that but it has to sit vertically centered between the top and bottom text which is one thing I cant get working properly and also when the screen scrolls the middle image should stay between to top and bottom text if possible as currently (depending on browser) it scrolls over the top of the text, also if portrait or landscape it just looks a total mess